# Domino Designer Plugin Ant class path

Tags: plugins, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I've build an osgi plug-in to wrap a jar files. I've been following this [guide](https://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in/).

In the last step, I can´t “Build all” to generate the update site because an error said that couldn't find the ant classpath

[image]

Any idea?
Thanks

The version that i'm using is Release 9.0.1FP9 
Revision 20170815.0729-FP9 (Release 9.0.1FP9)

Comment: what version of IBM Designer are you using?

Comment: Release 9.0.1FP9 
Revision 20170815.0729-FP9 (Release 9.0.1FP9)

Answer (score 0):

Try running Ant on the command line to see the full output. Here is a GitHub project showing specifically how to [run Ant tasks for Domino](https://github.com/lhervier/domino-ant-tasks#ant-tasks-for-domino).

Here also are some details about [setting the Ant classpath for a given build](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-create-classpath-lib-variable-ant-script) in **build.xml**:

```
<!-- create our ant classpath using the fileset task -->
<path id="class.path">

  <!-- include all jars in the lib directory and all sub-directories -->
  <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
  </fileset>

</path>
```

I find that Eclipse plugins often just assemble and execute terminal commands, but when they fail they tend not to be great at making clear the cause. Often, running the equivalent commands in the terminal (be they `ant`, `maven`, etc.) is clearer when failures occur because you'll see the full error output. And it gives you the added benefit--sometimes--of having a clearer understanding of what's happening under the hood.